# Examples of non-transitive sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What are some examples of non-transitive sets? I have conducted several searches on Google and also searched the math.stackexchange website. I have encountered intransitive sets before but cannot recall those examples.

Answer (score 2):

Most* sets aren't transitive.  For a set to be transitive,  elements are also subsets of the set.   This is true for, say, the ordinals....but not true for most sets.  For example, $\{a\}$ is not transitive,  because $a$ is an element of it but not a subset.

To address some of the comments, by "Most" I mean sets that you run into in the ordinary business of mathematics outside of set theory.

Comment: ...unless $a = \emptyset$.

Comment: In a very good sense most sets are transitive. This is similar to how most real numbers are irrational, but you are likely to meet a rational number if you try to think about a concrete number.

Comment: @Asaf  I guess you are talking about club filters.  But for any ordinal $\alpha$, most subsets of $\aleph_\alpha$ are not transitive in the sense of cardinality, which is also a very good sense.

Comment: That sounds plausible, but surprising... in what "very good sense" are we talking about?

Comment: @Trevor: I'm not disagreeing of course. In general, though, not just the ordinals, the class of transitive sets is closed under unions, and cofinal (every set is a subset of a transitive set), which makes this class fairly large as far as classes go.

Answer (score 1):

Any non-empty set without the empty set as an element. So $\{\{\{\}\}\}$ is easy.

Comment: The empty set is transitive, but does not have the empty set as an element.

Comment: Right, anything else. I have changed it accordingly.