# Why is {a} not transitive unless $a = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I am trying to understand what transitive sets look like or what not transitive sets look like. I found another thread where someone stated that $\{a\}$ is not transitive unless $a=\emptyset$. I don't quite understand why this is the case. Off course $a \in \{a\}$. But why is $a \nsubseteq \{a\}$
([Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324640/examples-of-non-transitive-sets)).
I have seen a video on YouTube where the guy stated that $F=\{F,G\}$ with $G=\{F\}$ would be transitive.
Those seems contradicting each other to me... ([Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8JiPLn_KqI))

Comment: Do you know the axiom of regularity, which would exclude your example $F$ and $G$?

Comment: No I did not know that. But is this the case here? As far as I am concerned axiom of regularity would forbid that $F=\{F\}$ but why would it forbid $F=\{F,\{F\}\}$

Comment: If there is such $F$, then $F\in\{F\}\in F$, so we have an infinite $\in$-decreasing chain.

Comment: Ok so the second example is nonsense ?

Comment: Yes and no. If you work with anti-foundational axioms, then such a set may exist. On the other hand, the axiom of regularity, which the usual formulation of set theory (like $\mathsf{ZF}$ assumes), proves there is no such $F$.

Comment: Thank you! But regardless of that why is $\{a\}$ not transitive then?

Comment: I will post an answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The key we need to prove the statement is the *axiom of regularity*, which states the membership relation $\in$ over the class of all sets $V$ is *well-founded*. (Well-foundedness is a generalization of well-orderedness, which is the extraction of 'every non-subset has a minimal element' from well-orderedness.) The formal statement of the axiom of regularity is

> For each non-empty set $x$, there is $y\in x$ such that $y$ is $\in$-minimal above $x$, in the sense that no $z\in y$ satisfies $z\in x$.

An important consequence (and an equivalent formulation if we assume the axiom of choice) is the following:

> There is no $\in$-decreasing chain, that is, no $\langle x_n\mid n<\omega\rangle$ satisfies $x_0\ni x_1\ni \cdots$.

The above fact excludes the presence of your $F$ as I commented. Moreover, we can prove from the regularity that $\{a\}$ is not transitive unless $a$ is empty:

> *Proof.* Assume that $\{a\}$ is transitive and $b\in a$. By transitivity, $b\in \{a\}$, so $b=a$. Hence $a,a,a,\cdots$ is an infinite $\in$-decreasing sequence that cannot exist by Regularity.

There are a bit more things I should explain about the axiom of regularity, but let me replace my answer with [a post on my webpage](https://hanuljeon95.github.io/Axiom-of-Regularity/).
On the other hand, some anti-foundational axioms prove there is your $F$. For example, Aczel's anti-foundation axiom proves the existence of $F=\{F,\{F\}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is not true unless you assume the [axiom of Regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity). For example let $a=\{a\}$, this Quine atom is singleton and it is transitive and of course $a$ is nonempty. But if you have the axiom of Regularity, then this axiom would prove that every set is not an element of itself, that is $$\forall x \forall y : y \in x \to y \neq x$$

The proof is easy, suppose that $x=y$, they by Separation we have $\{x\}$, now we have $x \in x$ [from $x=y$ and $y \in x$ and equality theory], so the only element of $\{x\}$ (which is $x$) shares an element (which is $x$) with $\{x\}$, clearly violating Regularity.

Now from that we can easily prove that if $\{a\}$ is transitive, then $a$ must be empty, since if $a$ has an element $b$ (i.e. $b \in a$), then from the above we  have $b \neq a$, then by transitivity $b$ must be an element of $\{a\}$, which is not! Therefore $a$ must be empty and so disjoint of $\{a\}$.

Of course the existence of $F=\{F,\{F\}\}$ contradicts Regularity in a clear way since all elements of $F$ shares an element (which is $F$ itself) with $F$ and therefore non of them is disjoint of $F$, and so $F$ clearly breaks Regularity.